# boot Debian installation through Console on SPARC

Tags: debian, installation, boot, sparc

I'm trying to boot Debian for installation through SER MGT Console without VGA
when trying to use:

```
(0) ok boot cdrom  - text
    Boot device: /pci@400/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/device@4/storage@0/disk@0:f  File and args: - text
    Bad magic number in disk label
    Can't open disk label package
    ERROR: boot-read fail
    Can't open boot device
```

and

```
{0} ok boot cdrom
Boot device: /pci@400/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/device@4/storage@0/disk@0:                  f  File and args:
Bad magic number in disk label
Can't open disk label package
ERROR: boot-read fail
```

Using: **Debian Proxmox VE 6**
Machine: **SPARC ENTERPRISE T5240**
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It can't work :

- Proxmox => x86 cpus
- T5240 => UltraSPARC T2+ cpus

Comment: u mean not supported?

Comment: no. technically it is not possible. Try to boot a Windows 10 iso on your T5240 if you do not trust me. After that try to boot a Solaris 11.4 Sparc iso file, the results should be much better.

Comment: I try to boot Solaris 11.4 and it's not supported any more,i was able to boot & install solaris 10 x64 successfully,but i want to install Proxmox for installing freenas,and about Debian there is installation check https://teklager.se/en/knowledge-base/installing-debian-over-serial-console-apu-board/, http://pcengines.info/forums/?page=post&id=51C5DE97-2D0E-40E9-BFF7-7F7FE30E18FE

Comment: Solaris 11 is supported until nov 2031  http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-hardware-301321.pdf

Comment: I repeat : running x86 code on Sparc systems does not work. It can't.